# Call function in formBuilder.group({})

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I create a reactive form, and when I create `formBuilder.group` I want to set next Id for the object in the array

```
 JSON
 this.getData = [{
"id": 0,
"first_name": "Aaaa",
"last_name": "Aaa aaaa"
}, {
"id": 1,
"first_name": "Bbbb",
"last_name": "Bbb Bbbbbb"
 }, {
"id": 2,
"first_name": "Cccc",
"last_name": "Cccccc"

}]


ngOnInit() {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    this.getData.map(function(o) {
      return o.id + 1;
    })
  ),
  first_name: "",
  last_name: ""
});
}
```

But for this `Math.max.apply` i get `null`

Is there any way to call the function here?

I also try to make function outside formBuilder like this

```
getNextId(){
Math.max.apply(
    Math,
    this.getData.map(function(o) {
      return o.id + 1;
    })
  )}
```

and call function in `formBuilder.group` like this
`id: this.getNextId()`

But still the same...

If I call this function outside form I get the correct number
Thnx

Comment: please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: the first argument of MAth.max.apply must be **null**, not Math. see https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/max#Examples. Using flat arrow `var nextId= Math.max(...this.getData.map(x=>x.id))+1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples) on MDN states, you have several ways of getting the max value from an array of numbers (here I've done `+1` to get the next ID).

Using `reduce()`:

```
getNextId() {
    return this.getData.map(d => d.id).reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b)) + 1;
}
```

Using `apply()`:

```
getNextId() {
    return Math.max.apply(null, this.getData.map(d => d.id)) + 1;
}
```

Using spread operator:

```
getNextId() {
    return Math.max(...this.getData.map(d => d.id)) + 1;
}
```